# How to download images from URL in a dataframe and label the set images with a specific id stored in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, image, for-loop, download

The dataframe `df` I have has the columns `['index', 'en_title', 'jp_title', 'en_description', 'jp_description', 'image_url', 'store_item_id']` and I would like to download images from the urls in the `'image url'` column and label them with the numbers in the column `'store_item_id'`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNNDr.png)

So far, I have tried:

```
import requests

image_url = list(df["image_url"])

for img in image_url:
    file_name = img.split('/')[-1]
    print("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
    r = requests.get(img, stream=True)
 # this should be file_name variable instead of "file_name" string 

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r:
        f.write(chunk)
```

It runs but I have none of the images downloaded, and I still haven't figured out how to label the images with the value in `'store_item_id'`.

Comment: what's the original dataframe?

Comment: Why `with open` outside of `for` loop?

Comment: @hongsy the original dataframe is like the screenshot - and like how I explained in the text before the code chunk!

Comment: @E. Zeytinci I moved in the with open and still have problems

Comment: @mathisfun123 can you share some image urls with me for testing?